# Kivy textinput see end

Tags: python, tkinter, kivy

This seems like something that would be useful, and maybe I've missed it, but does a Kivy Textinput have a method that is equivalent to tkinter's `Text.see(END)`? I've looked at `do_cursor_movement`, but that just moves the cursor, not what is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a bug with the cursor not being set properly vs the display on start up - in my example below, after adding the lines to the `TextInput` the cursor reads as `(0, 100)` even though the top of the text is actually displayed. This causes the Bottom button to do nothing - until you click in the `TextInput` (changing the cursor pos) or hit the Top button.

To see what I mean, just comment out `Clock.schedule_once(lambda _: setattr(root.ids['ti'], 'cursor', (0, 0)))`.

I've tested this code as working with Kivy 1.8.1-dev (git: 1149da6bf26ff5f27536222b4ba6a874456cde6e) on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.1')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock

root = Builder.load_string('''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: ti

        Label:
            size_hint_x: None
            width: sp(80)
            text: str(ti.cursor)

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: sp(128)

        Widget

        Button:
            text: 'Top'
            on_press: ti.cursor = (0, 0)
        Button:
            text: 'Bottom'
            on_press: ti.cursor = (0, len(ti._lines) - 1)

        Widget
''')

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        text = ''
        for i in xrange(100):
            text += 'Line %d\n' % (i + 1,)
        root.ids['ti'].text = text

        # fix the cursor pos
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda _: setattr(root.ids['ti'], 'cursor', (0, 0)))
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found that the problem is solved by working with the ScrollView that contains the TextInput. With the following in a .kv file

```
ScrollView:
    id: scroll1
    size_hint_x: 0.6
    TextInput:
        readonly: True
        id: main
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: max(self.minimum_height, scroll1.height)
```

Then all one needs to do is call `self.ids['scroll1'].scroll_y = 0` This will scroll the TextInput to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar to Kivy at all, nor did I test about my answer, but if I understand the [docs](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html#kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput.cursor) correctly, by just setting the attribute `cursor` to the end of the line could do what you want.

Quoting:

> cursor
>
> ```
> Tuple of (row, col) values indicating the current cursor position.
> ```
>
> You can set a new (row, col) if you want to move the cursor. The
>   scrolling area will be automatically updated to ensure that the cursor
>   is visible inside the viewport.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but adjusting the location of the cursor doesn't change what the text input display.

Comment: This sounds weird, since their docs explicitly states "...ensure that the cursor is visible..."

Comment: Their docs must not be totally accurate. What's also strange is that when I was experimenting with cursor, I found that it isn't a (row, col) tuple, it's a (col, row) tuple.

Comment: That's too bad :( Sorry for the noise then

Comment: As Robert Burns once wrote, The best-laid schemes o' mice an' men
gang aft agley (go off astray).

Comment: Yes, it's `(col, row)`, and it does change the text display. It's how the End key works. If it doesn't work for you, and you are using `(col, row)` and not `(row, col)`, try updating Kivy.

Comment: I'm running 1.8 so the version of Kivy shouldn't be an issue. Suppose I have 35 lines of text. I've tried `textinput.cursor = (35,0)` and `textinput.cursor = (0,35)` and nothing happened in either case. I tried playing with `textinput.scroll_y` I could have it scroll down say 5 lines, but the 5 lines above got removed, and 5 blank lines were added to the bottom.